# how to move the the image to right side of the li manu?

Tags: html, css

I have image (orange flower) , I want to move it to right side in the li.

The image embedded in the `<a>` tag and I write `float:right;` but it is not working.

I donwt know why, I need help, many thanks.

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/5gGum/22/)

```
    <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="learnmore.html">פרטים נוספים</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">learnmore</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about_us.html">about_us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="prices.html">prices</a></li>
                    <li><a href="location.html">location</a></li>
            </ul>​
* { 
    margin:0; padding:0;
    border:0; diraction:rtl;
}
 body{
     text-align:right;
     font-family:Arial;
     font-size: 20px;
     border:1px solid red;
     font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#a7a7a7;
     line-height:20px
}
#menu { width:100%;
        border: 5px solid green;
        padding:18px 30px 0 0; border-bottom:1px solid #e2e2e2;}
#menu li { 
    border: 5px solid brown;float:right;padding-right:30px;}
#menu li a{ 

    right:0;
 text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; 
 color:#2c2c25; font-size:18px; line-height:20px;
    float:right; right:0;
     background:url(http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP4bAv-ruMbgWa8rTLZhWOITQk6aGOI8L_YMrmsRbacuIR502w) 
    7px 1px no-repeat;

}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `background-position: right;` in li.

```
#menu li {
border: 5px solid brown;float:right;padding-right:30px;
background:url(http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP4bAv-ruMbgWa8rTLZhWOITQk6aGOI8L_YMrmsRbacuIR502w)
7px 1px no-repeat;
background-position: right;
   }
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gGum/23/)

Answer (score 1):

You add this style for a

```
a{
   display:block;
 }
```

and remove `right:0`

Answer (score 1):

Think you'll want to try

```
background-position:right;
```

For `#menu li`.

Answer (score 1):

**background shorthand** is wrong, try

```
background:url(http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP4bAv-ruMbgWa8rTLZhWOITQk6aGOI8L_YMrmsRbacuIR502w) 
    no-repeat center right;
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5gGum/27/) with minimal CSS

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is not a tag in itself, because you put it as background-image to the link, that's why `float:right` does not work.
So you would need:

```
background:url("http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP4bAv-ruMbgWa8rTLZhWOITQk6aGOI8L_YMrmsRbacuIR502w") top right no-repeat;
```

to position the image. Or `bottom right`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
background:url(http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP4bAv-ruMbgWa8rTLZhWOITQk6aGOI8L_YMrmsRbacuIR502w) 
**right** 1px no-repeat;
```

I changed your "7px" in the background to "right", meaning it will place it horizontally to the right, and 1 px from the top.

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-position:right;` on `#menu li a`, and adjust the paddings, with something like `padding-right:10px;` on `#menu li` and `padding-right:15px;` on `#menu li a`.

You can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5gGum/29/